# Fetch json API in Node.js v18

Tags: javascript, rest, async-await, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch API from an URL in JavaScript and this is my code:

```
    try {
        let response = await fetch(URL, {
            method: 'GET',
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log("Err")
    }
```

Error I got:

```
(node:403113) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4045
            if (socket[kParser].timeoutType !== TIMEOUT_IDLE) {
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'timeoutType')
    at _resume (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4045:33)
    at resume (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4015:7)
    at connect (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4004:7)
Node.js v18.6.0
```

I googled and what I know is I should run it on Node.js v16 :((

Comment: What version of node are you currently using? 18 or 16? [In version 18 `fetch` is not experimental.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Unrelated to this, but `console.log(data.json())` should be just `console.log(data)`

Comment: I'm using Node.js v18.6.0 and thank @Ch

Comment: @evolutionxbox Node v18 still presents that warning :(

Comment: @jabaa obviously… :P

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue, using node v18.0.0

Comment: Which URL is it?

Comment: @robertklep: _"[Note that this is experimental for a reason.](https://twitter.com/matteocollina/status/1516500901296549889) The performance of the WHATWG streams and fetch is not good atm."

Comment: I tried it with `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` and it works until `console.log(data.json());`. There, I get: `TypeError: data.json is not a function`. That makes sense, because `response.json` parses JSON and returns the result. JSON can't contain functions.

Comment: know it's supposed to be consolo.log(data). Its my fault

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I got the answer on a Indian guy Youtube channel.
Instead of using `fetch`, I use axios.get for getting the data from Json API.
Thanks for you all supporting <3
So it becomes:

```
let URL ="......."       
try {
    let response = await axios.get(URL);
    let to_return = await response.data;
    console.log(to_return);
}
catch(err) {
    console.log("Err")
}
```